# how to make smooth level(peak) meter with Qt

Tags: qt, qpainter

get peak levels from channels:

```
BASS_ChannelGetLevelEx(chan, levels, 0.02, BASS_LEVEL_STEREO    );
```

this function i call in thread with same frequency

```
void Thread::run()
{ 

 while(!m_abort)
    {

        emit SetLevels();
        QThread::msleep(20);
    }
}
```

level meter draw via QPainter

that's what happens

[image]

running like crazy, making sharp jumps. but must be smoothly

how make it level smoothly?

Comment: You need to interpolate peak levels to do more smooth animation. Take a look at `QPropertyAnimation` class, it does what you need.

Comment: can more detail about interpolation?

Comment: Sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation , but Qt already implements it: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeasingcurve.html

Comment: new_level_left=(levels[1]+previous_level_left)/2;  ?

Comment: You need to decide, what you want to do: 1) just use Qt or 2) try to create your own code that already has an implementation in Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your new peak value is greater than the current peak value, then just assign the new value. If it's less then decrease the current value in a logarithmic way like so..

```
float factor = 0.10;
cur_left_value = cur_left_value - factor * (cur_left_value - new_left_value);
```

The greater the factor is, the faster your peak meters will "fall". You will have to have a timer or thread to **continuously** assign the latest (new) peak values with the logic explained above.